# OkHttp image type

Tags: android, okhttp

When I upload an image okHttp only accepts `PNG`? When I try `jpg` it denies.

This is my code:

```
public static Boolean uploadFile(final File file, final Context context) {
        AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPG = MediaType.parse("image");

                    //employee verkrijgen
                    DataLayer dataLayer = new DataLayer(context);
                    Employee employee = dataLayer.getEmployee();
                    dataLayer.close();

                    //request body aanmaken
                    RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                            .addFormDataPart("ProfilePicture", file.getName(),
                                    RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG,file))
                            .addFormDataPart("api_token", employee.getApiToken())
                            .build();

                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(static_urls.Employee.uploadProfilePicture(employee.getEmployeeId())).post(formBody).build();
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    String responseString = response.body().string().substring(5000, response.body().string().length());

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.e("upload",Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what error message you get?

Comment: No error the image is not send with the request.

Comment: have you tried `"image/*"` or `"image/jpeg"` as `MediaType`?

Comment: Yes I tried both but is not working.

Comment: Can you post your working PNG code as well so we can compare?

Answer (score 2):

use 
`MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");`

[Here is](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html) full list of mime types